# Is there a way for angular-chosen that when I search text but showing options with icons in AngularJs?

Tags: angularjs, select, plugins, jquery-select2

For example, I have a list of elements like following:

```
[{
  id: 1,
  name: 'The only planet with life that currently found',
  icon: 'base64-blablalbla',
  abbr: 'Earth'
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'Another string that describes M*a*r*s',
  icon: 'base64-blablalbla',
  abbr: 'Mars'
}, {
  id: 3,
  name: 'Another string that describes M*o*o*n',
  icon: 'base64-blablalbla',
  abbr: 'Moon'
}]
```

I want to use chosen plugin that when I search "ar"(hit Earth and Mars) on "abbr" field， the selections that displays their icons will be shown. Unlike the general behavior, search the "name" field, showing the "name" field, my requirement is to search the "abbr" field, but showing the "icon" field, or showing name+icon or that I can customize it will be the best.

select2 or any other plugin is also welcome.

Any one can help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a plunker of what you have achieved by now?

Comment: I forked from someone, here it is: https://plnkr.co/edit/UG531tnY2tDJOvFOuYNQ?p=preview

Comment: Since the base64 icon has two much data, searching text on field A, but showing text of field B is ok. I can achieve it step by step.

Comment: AAH! this is for AngularJs (angular 1), not Angular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this whit a CustomPipe:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items | yourCustomPipe:'id,text':query">
    <i [ngClass]="item.icon"></i>
</div>
```

But be carreful, [Pipe can slow your app](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe)

So and then, you have a [custom Pipe which will filter your items](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#custom-pipes).

Comment: Thanks Wandrille, that's very helpful for me and I'll try your answer.